# Paramaterized batch insert into spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, insert, spring-batch

I'm trying to create a function to batch insert data into different tables using Spring JDBC. I am looking at section 13.4 of http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html to see how I can do it, but it doesn't show any examples when list of columns and values are dynamically generated.

In Python and cx_Oracle all I did was to do that using insertmany by passing a sql statement and a dictionary consists of (column: values) to it.

Is there any ways to achieve the same thing on Java using Spring JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public final SimpleJdbcInsert create(String tableName, String columnNames)
{
    return new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate).withTableName(tableName)
            .usingColumns(getTokens(columnNames));
}

final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
/*
* columnName1 is in columnNames
*/
parameters.put("columnName1", value1);

final SimpleJdbcInsert insert = create(table, columnNames);
insert.execute(parameters);
```